# Issues with Android Studio after upgrade from 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing the issue with android studio. I have updated the android studio to 2.2.2 yesterday. Now i am not able to create new project. When i create one, i found these errors.
While old project is working.

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

I am using "jdk1.8.0_101".

I have tried all possible solutions on stack overflow, nothing found useful.

**Note :** Please don't mark it as a duplicate question. I have read them all, and tried almost all those given solutions.

**some Solutions i have tried**

1. Deleted .gradle file from User dir. (C:\user...gradle).
2. unistalled android studio.. again re-installed.
3. Added max size to gradle....
4. added in settings\compiler\vm options.
5. caching restart.

Comment: increase `HeapSize` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did it.. no luck :(

Comment: for test case call down grade vesion `jdk1.8.0_92`

Comment: "*almost all*"?

Comment: Try deleting your gradle.properties

Comment: @AbAppletic yeah.. "almost all" ...  deleted but doesn't work.. even new project is not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the latest version of Android Studio. please delete existing android-studio and from tools.android.com download previous 2.2.1 version

Answer (score 0):

I changed gradle.properties

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

and it worked.